# How to convert a bipartite graph into no bipartite

Tags: python-3.x, graph, networkx, bipartite

I've been trying to do this for a long time without success, so I'd better ask you.

First of all, I'm working on **python 3** and **networkx**.

I have a **bipartite graph** as the **image A**, in which there are two types of nodes according to their 'group' attribute (group='R' and group='X'). Also, some relationships are reversible, as R4, and some are not (so I guess we would have to unfold the node in those cases).

What I need is to **leave only the nodes of the R group** and eliminate the X ones, but **keeping the relations between them**. That is, **convert the green nodes into edges and keep a graph of only blue nodes**.

Ohhh please!!, Can someone give me a hand?

Any help would be very welcome.

Thank you in advance wholeheartedly!

> GRAPH IMAGE HERE:
>
> https://media.springernature.com/full/springer-static/image/art%3A10.1038%2Fs41540-018-0067-y/MediaObjects/41540_2018_67_Fig1_HTML.png

Comment: Can you restate the problem a bit differently?  You have an existing bipartite graph.  You want to create a new graph, which consists of only one of these groups.  What does an edge in the new graph mean?  [note, look at the project command in networkx since that sounds somewhat likely to be what you're after]

Answer (score 0):

Go over nodes of the graph, if the node is green add an edge between all its neighbours (which will only be blue). At the end remove all the green nodes.

```
to_remove = []
for node in G.nodes(data = True):
    if node[1]["type"] == "Green": ## check if the node is green
        to_remove.append(node[0])
        ## go over all neighbours of the node and add an edge between them
        neighbours =  list(G.neighbors(node[0]))
        for i in range(0, len(neighbours)-1):
            for j in range(i+1, len(neighbours)):
                G.add_edge(neighbours[i],neighbours[j])

## remove the green nodes
G.remove_nodes_from(to_remove)
```